# Android Studio: Write a build task, in order to have enums from an enum-formatted attr within a declare-stylable accessible by their name at runtime

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, enums, task

In my other question ([Get enum values (from within declare-stylable) defined in xml file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868824/get-enum-values-from-within-declare-stylable-defined-in-xml-file-programmatica)), the reputable user Mike M. (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) suggests writing a build task in his very first comment, in order to make the `enum`s from an enum-formatted `attr` within a `declare-stylable` accessible at runtime by their name, just like one would access other resources at runtime (for instance a string resource via `getResources.getString(R.string.myString)`).

My fellow geniuses, the question is: How would I write such build task?

Comment: What happens if a question is too difficult for the community?

Comment: What do I do in such cases?