# Custom visibility xml params

Tags: android, view, visibility, custom-attributes

I want to create a new xml parameter for one of my custom views to handle the visibility of something within it. I can do it other ways of course, but I would like to do it in a way that I can use normal android params to change it.

something like:

```
<MyCustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:my_custom_visibility="gone"/>
```

so I coulg just do

```
viewToBeHidden.visibility = a.getInt(R.styleable.my_custom_view_my_custom_visibility, View.Visible);
```

I tried because visibilities are integers but it doesn't let me put gone in the view declaration

```
<attr name="my_custom_visibility" format="integer" />
```

using

```
<attr name="my_custom_visibility" format="reference" />
```

results in a compilation error:

```
AAPT: error: 'gone' is incompatible with attribute my_custom_visibility (attr) reference [weak].
```

the other types available for the attribute don't seem to apply to this case.

is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: try enum type as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341705/9241978

Comment: the return types is enum for View.Visible | View.Gone.. not ineteger

Comment: thought there will be a better way to do it thanks to both

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Pawel and @Sam comments, I created a dedicated enum attribute like this:

```
<attr name="my_custom_visibility" format="enum">
            <enum name="gone" value="8" />
            <enum name="invisible" value="4" />
            <enum name="visible" value="0" />
        </attr>
```

and use it like this in the view:

```
viewToBeHidden.visibility = attrs.getInt(R.styleable.my_custom_view_my_custom_visibility, View.VISIBLE);
```

so it would feel just as the "original" one