# Can I use enum from code in android custom enum attribute?

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-attributes, attrs.xml

I have an enum in my Kotlin app:

```
enum class MeasurementUnits(val displayString: String) {
    KILOGRAM("kg"),
    POUND("lbs"),
    KILOMETER("km"),
    MILE("mi"),
}
```

I'd like to use this enum in a custom attribute in a compound View I'm writing, like so:

```
<com.myapp.MyCustomView
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    custom:display_units="KILOMETER" />
```

But the only way I see of defining this attribute as an enum is separate and unrelated to the enum, in `attrs.xml`:

```
<attr name="input_units" format="enum">
   <enum name="KILOGRAM" value="0"/>
   <enum name="POUND" value="1"/>
   <enum name="KILOMETER" value="2"/>
   <enum name="MILE" value="3"/>
</attr>
```

This is weird, since I'm re-defining the enum again, and it's super fragile - they must be completely in sync, any changes must be done in the same place.
I don't want to just write it as string since this is super fragile too, but it's slightly better - at least I don't force the order to be the same.

Is there a way to define a custom enum attribute, and point to the enum class in my code?
Or at least make sure the lists are in sync?

What's the best practice here?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58815613/8084314

Comment: @MoeinDeveloper Yes I saw that, thanks. Getting the value of the enum is easier, but I still have to maintain 2 identical lists in my code, and if god forbid one is changed and the other is not, I'm screwed

Comment: Seems like there's no other way, Check Lottie's enum: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml

Comment: I just found this repo on github, I thought it might be usefull to you: https://github.com/afterecho/create_enum_from_xml