# Setting text size to dynamically created EditText widgets produces different size for different android screens

Tags: android

I am adding EditText dynamically on press of Add button. I have handled dynamic creation of widgets and adding them to existing xml layout. But the problem is in the text size. I am using 15 SP in xml layout and want to keep the same size for dynamically created ones also.

I have applied the following code to calculate the text size dynamically:

```
int txtSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
EditText child = new EditText(MyActivity.this); 
child.setTextSize(txtSize);
```

Its not producing the desired results and text size varies according to different screen sizes in spite of the fact that I am using Scaled Pixels.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Define alternative "style" resource for devices with different screen size.

   - Create res/values-sw480dp and res/values-sw720dp folder (assuming you need to handle screen width 480 and 720 pixels)
   - Add a styles.xml in the each resource folder with different screen size
   - styles.xml contains a style like the following:

   `<style name="DetailText">
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/detail_text_color</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
       <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
   </style>`

   - Use different textSize in the style file for screen with different size
   - For detail of how to create alternative resource for screen with different sizes, use this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
2. Add logic in your code to retrieve the text size from the style file. This link shows you how to retrieve valute of attribute in style file: [How to retrieve style attributes programmatically from styles.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719103/how-to-retrieve-style-attributes-programatically-from-styles-xml)

Comment: Thanks Mei-Lin for the answer. Actually above solution worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int textSize = 15;
EditText child = new EditText(MyActivity.this); 
child.setTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Sp, textSize);
```

Comment: I'm working on C# and this works for me, maybe you need to change a little bit this code to work on java but should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Ivan Verges, its working, I replaced with this for Java language 'child.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15)'

Answer (score 0):

just write this code

```
EditText child = new EditText(MyActivity.this); 
child.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
```

reference

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#COMPLEX_UNIT_SP