# obtainStyledAttributes annotated with @StyleableRes. Suppress warnings

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-studio, android-resources

While looking at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719103/how-to-retrieve-style-attributes-programatically-from-styles-xml), I was having problems on the line:

```
TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.MyCustomStyle, attrs);
```

It seems that Android Studio won't let me pass in an int that doesn't come from a `R.styleable` resource without gettings warnings.

It tells me that it expects a resource of type styleable, which I assume means that the code I'm calling has been annotated with the [@StyleableRes annotation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/support/annotation/StyleableRes.java?av=f)

[image: Expected resource of type styleable]

What would be the best course of action to read the values defined in the R.style.{x}? The accepted answer on the linked post works and compiles, but I don't know how to suppress the warning. As there's a warning, is it safe to suppress? If so, how?

Comment: A `styleable` is not a `style`

Comment: @blackbelt correct. That's why I'm confused that the accepted (bounty!) answer in the question I linked to is using a style and has so many upvotes.

Comment: in fact it's just a warning, did you run your code?

Comment: The code compiles. For the moment, I'm using @SuppressWarnings("all"), but it's not ideal. I want to explicitly say in the code "I'm aware of this warning and it can be ignored" but only for that one call on obtainStyledAttributes. I could create a method containing only that line to extract the TypedArray and annotate that method, but it's seems like a work around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the correct way to suppress this :

```
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
```

I'm offered this when I press Alt-Enter to bring up fixes for the warning and choose **Inspection 'Constant and Resource Type Mismatches' options** > **Suppress for class** (screenshot attached)[image].

It works for me.

It's possible that the ID for this inspection has changed since whatever code you were referencing was written; I looked briefly through the commit logs but couldn't find a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've suppressed that specific warning now. Is it safe to mute the warning (I'm guessing it's a warning for a reason)?

Comment: You might not want to mute it everywhere all the time. This bug notwithstanding, it does flag an easy-to-make but difficult-to-diagnose programming error.

Comment: Set that suppression to method is enough and safer .. no need to take it wild to whole class..

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress warning checking with `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")` for the method in which the problem is or you can just use `//noinspection ResourceType` just before that line to avoid inspection only in that line of code.