# Change value of item in style.xml programmatically android

Tags: android

I am new to android development and currently making a calculator app. In it, my activity has number of buttons on which I apply the same style. The structure of code is something like as below

**layout.xml**

    `<LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:text="Button 1"
            style="@style/styleName"
            >
        <Button
            android:text="Button 2"
            style="@style/styleName"
            >
        <Button
            android:text="Button 3"
            style="@style/styleName"
            >
    </LinearLayout>`

**style.xml**

`<resources>
        <style name="styleName">
            <item name="attribute1">attribute1Value</item>
            <item name="attribute2">attribute2Value</item>
            <item name="attribute3">attribute3Value</item>
            <item name="android:background">BackgroundValue</item>
        </style>
    </resources>`

Now I want to provide a feature to user in which when he/she selects a particular theme from the setting, the background of all buttons will change. This can be achieved if I can change the value of background color  in styleName. I am not sure how to achieve this. I look around the web and didn't find any satisfying answer for achieving the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719103/how-to-retrieve-style-attributes-programatically-from-styles-xml Did you try this?

Comment: The above link is for getting the value but the requirement is for changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you cannot change style programmatically.if i were you, i would create many `selector.xml` in `/res/drawable/` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/light_btn_pressed" />
   <item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/light_btn_normal" />
</selector>
```

For each "style" you will have a selector (light,dark,..etc).
Insert in drawable your colors or images.
After these, you can apply these selectors by setting `android:background="@drawable/my_button"`.
Additional, with this method you will achieve also the interaction on button states.

I hope it helps

Comment: Have in mind that do not all sdks support same themes.

Answer (score -1):

You can have access the attributes of style xml through Typed array.
suppose you have a customstyle xml.

```
 int[] attrs ={android.R.attr.textColor, android.R.attr.background,android.R.attr.text};
TypedArray array = obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.CustomStyle, attrs);

// Fetching the colors defined in your style
int textColor = array.getColor(0, Color.BLACK);
int backgroundColor = array.getColor(1, Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: In this answer you can get the value but the question is regarding changing the value.