# How to set arbitrary theme colors at runtime

Tags: android

I would like to theme an app using arbitrary colors at runtime. I figured out how to set multiple themes at compile time and how to apply different themes at runtime (as long as the themes are defined at compile time) but I can't figure out if it's possible to define and apply an arbitrary theme at runtime.

What I'm trying to do is download a color list from a server at runtime and define a theme using those colors and then apply the theme.

Is it possible to do this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797436/how-to-programmatically-create-an-android-theme-style), it's **NOT** possible. Its answer is from December 2016, so quite recent.