# Are themes in android immutable?

Tags: android

I read in multiple places that themes are immutable. However, from this  [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#applyStyle(int, boolean)) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905131/4009347), I don't see how that is true. What do people mean when they say themes are immutable?

Comment: Yes it's immutable you can't edit the theme pragmatically

Answer (score 2):

By immutable they mean that if you define a theme in a styles file, in XML, you cannot change its properties dynamically (programatically).

See the answer provided here: [How to programmatically create an Android theme style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797436/how-to-programmatically-create-an-android-theme-style)