# android app theme on the basis of colour code received from API

Tags: android, themes

The App theme should be changed on the basis of color code provided by API. The color of the action bar, app background, etc.

I know how to change the theme by adding multiple themes in styles.xml and using the required theme from the same.

But here the requirement is that I need to change the app theme from the color codes received from API.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help you with your question, please share some more information about what you're trying to achieve and what you've already tried. Perhaps share some of the code you are using. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically create an Android theme style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797436/how-to-programmatically-create-an-android-theme-style)