# What's the simplest and most efficient way to associate different data in XML?

Tags: android, xml

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to access from code two related resources.

Consider this example, the best solution I can think of to my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="black">⬛</string><color name="black_c">#000000</color>
    <string name="white">⬜</string><color name="white_c">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Given a string N in my code I can access both the second string associated to it (⬛ or ⬜) or the color by adding "_c" to the end of the N string.

So, if N="black" I can use N to retrieve both ⬛ and #000000 (with N + "_c")

Is there a better way to do this? My solution feels a bit hacky. Hope I managed to explain what I'm trying to achieve, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another proposal. I hope it will help you.

If you have a colors.xml and a strings.xml (within the values directory)

```
<!-- colors.xml -->
<resources>
    <color name="black">#000000</color >
</resources> 

<!-- strings.xml -->
<resources>
    <string name="black">Some black string</string>
</resources>
```

Using the same name you can access both of them if you are able to get the different id (ie R.string.black or R.color.black). The `getIdentifier`()` method can do it. So you can try (not tested)

```
String name = "black;
String choice = "color"; //or "string" dependending on if you want the color or the string
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(name, choice, getPackageName());
Resources resources = getResources();

//Then access using
//If choice=="color"
int color = resources.getColor(resId);

//If choice=="string"
String text = resources.getString(resId);
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't thought about this, it's way better than my solution. I corrected one of the xml files name in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ya it sounds a bit hacky. You could use styles to group all your resources (as attributes to that style) and then read those styles. More info here: [How to retrieve style attributes programmatically from styles.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719103/how-to-retrieve-style-attributes-programatically-from-styles-xml)

But this again sounds hacky. What's your actual requirement? The way you suggested sounds OK. You can go ahead with that implementation since from a performance standpoint, it doesn't take any extra over head. Just make sure you write a neat API to fetch data from your xml.