# Programmatically get color from resource using ContextCompat that doesn't ignore night qualifier

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-styles

I'm currently using `ContextCompat.getColor`, however it's not fetching the correct colour. When the app is adhering to the night resource qualifier, ContextCompat fetches the color from `values/colors.xml` and not `values-night/colors.xml`.

I've tried apporaches like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952929/333733 using a theme with one residing in `values/styles.xml` and `values-night/styles.xml` but it seems the color is precompiled using the resource folder without the `-night` qualifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for which mode the theme is in yourself:

```
int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode
        & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // Night mode is not active, we're in day time
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        // Night mode is active, we're at night!
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED:
        // We don't know what mode we're in, assume notnight
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94#.l2fswuy4z