How to programmatically grab a Color defined in a style?
I have the following attributes defined as 'colors' in attr.xml:
<attr name="darkC" format="reference|color" />
<attr name="normalC" format="reference|color" />
<attr name="mediumC" format="reference|color" />
<attr name="lightC" format="reference|color" />

This is so that I can then define values for those colors - styles.xml:
   <style name="GreyTheme" parent="@style/BaseMaterialThemeNoActionBar">
        <item name="darkC">@color/darkGrey</item>
        <item name="normalC">@color/normalGrey</item>
        <item name="mediumC">@color/mediumGrey</item>
        <item name="lightC">@color/lightGrey</item>
   </style>

   <style name="WhiteTheme" parent="@style/BaseMaterialThemeNoActionBar">
        <item name="darkC">@color/darkWhite</item>
        <item name="normalC">@color/normalWhite</item>
        <item name="mediumC">@color/mediumWhite</item>
        <item name="lightC">@color/lightWhite</item>
   </style>

   <style name="GreenTheme" parent="@style/BaseMaterialThemeNoActionBar">
        <item name="darkC">@color/darkGreen</item>
        <item name="normalC">@color/normalGreen</item>
        <item name="mediumC">@color/mediumGreen</item>
        <item name="lightC">@color/lightGreen</item>
   </style>

Now, in my Java code, I need to programmatically grab the color 'darkC' and use it.
Were it a real color defined in colors.xml like so
    <color name="darkGreen">#ff009900</color>

I would be able to grab in like this in my Java code
ColorStateList colorG = ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.darkGreen));

but 'resources.getColor(R.attr.darkC)' doesn't seem to work - it crashes in runtime with android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException.
How can I grab this color then?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719103/how-to-retrieve-style-attributes-programmatically-from-styles-xml
